# How do I change the shortlink to a post in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I created a wordpress (Version 3.3.1) site on a staging server and created some posts.  Once I got it looking the way I wanted it to, I switch the site url to the production url.  Unfortunately, all the shortlinks are still resolving to my staging server.  How can I update the shortlinks on all the posts?

Comment: Try http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you didn't migrate the database correctly or perhaps the setting in Wordpress still points to your old domain? Also, I have seen .htaccess files in the root directory causing an issue like this. Confirm these 3 things are configured properly!